# How to see mongodb data from .ns files

Tags: php, mongodb

I have just explored the mongodb. When ever i store the data using mongo. It will store that data in *.ns file.

So how can I see data stored from the .NS file?

When I had tried to open this file in notepad++, it shows lots of NULL.

Is there any other way to check the data stored in mobgodb.?

Comment: This question is off topic on Stackoverflow, which is aimed at _programming_ questions. Please ask this question at the more appropriate http://dba.stackexchange.com and delete it here.

Comment: Please check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489611/mongodb-created-files. the link have correct answer for your question. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I believe the data itself is not saved in the NS files, but on files with extension `.0`,`.1` etc. with same name. Those files are not designed to be read with text editors.

Probably the easiest way is to **start a mongod process** by pointing to the folder where you have the files (`mongod --dbpath /path/to/your/files/`). Then you can just use mongo shell to explore the contents.

You do get some cleartext portions of the datafiles, but mostly it's unreadable with typical text-editor.

dbname.0 is the pre-allocated initial datafile , which starts with 64MB

dbname.ns is for book-keeping. ns stands for namespace. The default limit for the 16MB .ns file supports 24,000 namespaces (collections + indexes) (see: --nssize parameter)

whenever MongoDB grows beyond the size of the last dbname.x file, it allocates a new data file with twice the size, up to size 2GB. Once the file size reaches 2GB, each successive file is also 2GB.