# MongoDB created files

Tags: file, mongodb

I'm trying MongoDB but I don't understand the files created by it.

If I create a document on my db collection lets say **users**, it will create these files on my **/data/db/**

```
_tmp (folder)
mongod.lock
users.0 - 16.8MB
users.1 - 33.6MB
users.ns - 16.8MB
```

I've added some documents and the files size haven't changed..I'm a bit lost here...does anyone know how those files work? I've tried to open them with gedit/vim and nothing.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "users" would be database? These files correspond to your database not collection. Isn't it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The .0, .1 files are datafiles. Each datafile is preallocated to a particular size.  (This is done to prevent file system fragmentation, among other reasons.)  The first filename for a database is .0, then .1, etc.  .0 will be 64MB, .1 128MB, et cetera, up to 2GB.  Once the files reach 2GB in size, each successive file is also 2GB.
Information regarding datafiles can be found here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space

The ".ns" files are namespace files. Each collection and index would count as a namespace. Each namespace is 628 bytes, the .ns file is 16MB by default.

Thus if every collection had one index, we can create up to 12,000 collections.  The --nssize parameter allows you to increase this limit.

Maximum .ns file size is 2GB.

Comment: +1 for a good, thorough description. You missed the _tmp folder and the lock, though. :)

Comment: Hi ! I want to create a replica set , what is the database extension ? 
should I use .0 or .1 or .ns ?

Comment: Did not get the 12000 collections statement..Please shed some light

Comment: If collections and indices are namespaces, what goes into the data files?

Answer (score 1):

Mongo pre-allocates space in chunks, so your file size will stay at 16Mb until you have more than 16Mb of data, and it rolls over a new chunk.

Comment: so I suppose users.0 and users.1 are those files where my documents will be stored and what about users.ns and why users.0 and .1? I don't have all that information..I have just one user added

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head but I'm not sure why you would even care -- these are binary files used exclusively by the Mongo backend. They're not intended to be used by you directly.

Comment: users.ns is namespace, which by default is that 16.8MB size, and it won't grow unless you change your configuration. It holds things like collection names, and probably other things that I don't know about.

Comment: I'm guessing .0 has your data and .1 has your index(es), but I don't know for sure. Needing to know what each file has hasn't come up for me, in my one year of mongo experience. :)

Comment: @WesFreeman thanks a lot for your comment...plz paste them as answer so I can accept

Comment: I was thinking that you'd get a .2 after 16Mb of data was inserted, but I'm now starting to think that's not correct. I don't recall offhand and I don't have my mongo install nearby. In any case, I think we can agree that it doesn't much matter. :)

Comment: @AlexHowansky I want to know what those files are because I need to be sure of what is happening on my server =) and I'm thinking about using MongoDB on a new application

Comment: It's useful to know for backup purposes (although I would just copy the entire data folder, if you really want to do file copying backups). Make sure you have journaling enabled if you plan to just copy the files--see here for more info: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Backups

Comment: Alex got it mostly right--why don't you add a bit to your answer so he can accept it. By the way, guessing again, but mongo occasionally needs to create temporary files, such as when it is merging large result sets and creating large indexes. I imagine that's what goes in the _tmp folder.

Comment: The .0 datafile is 64m, then .1 is 128m and so on, up to 2g max. You can find some more information regarding this here:

Comment: Okay, here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space Take a look at the Datafile Preallocation section of the link. That should help!