# Restored Mongo DB Missing Some Data Files

Tags: mongodb

I am migrating a DB from one server to another, and let's say that due to circumstances beyond my control, we are limited to "cut & paste".  That's simply not feasible with ~66GB worth of files (.0, .1, and .ns -- a few hundred of each of these).

One idea I have is to copy only the dump files and then use `mongorestore` to restore the DB from the backup. The dump files total only a few megabytes, so it will be easy to copy these from one environment to the other.

To test this approach I do the following on my Dev environment.

First, I create a backup the existing DB:

```
mongodump --dbpath z:\mongodata\db -o c:\mongodb\backup --journal
```

Then, I can restore it (or, essentially "copy" it from the backup) using:

```
mongorestore --dbpath c:\mongodb\data c:\mongodb\backup
```

However, what I notice is that the original DB (*z:\mongodata\db*) contains .0, *and* .1 files in addition to the namespace files.

[image]

The restored DB only contains .0 and .ns files, and does not contain the .1 file:

[image]

I understand these are the "data files" that Mongod uses and they are [created to a pre-allocated size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489611/mongodb-created-files), but I don't understand why the restored version doesn't contain *all* the files that the original version contains.

My suspicion is that Mongo creates the .0 and the .1 by default, but that the .1 is simply not needed or used, and `mongorestore` is able to discern this from the BSON data, and creates the restored version omitting the .1 which isn't needed.

Am I on the right track with this? Or should I be worried that the `mongorestore` is not preserving the .1 files?

Comment: How about setting up replica and let mongo do it's magic.

Comment: @Saleem I am not a DBA, and have very little experience using mongo shell or pymongo but I'm not sure replication is the solution here. We are decommissioning Server A, and migrating everything to Server B. I need a physical *copy* of the DB to exist on Server B, so that I can do E2E test on the applications which rely on the DB.

Comment: Purpose of setting up a replica server is just to take backup of existing server. Once data is copied over, you can retire older machine. However, there is another solution. Just copy  db folder and move to new machine and start mongod specifying db folder.

Comment: @Saleem the DB folder is 66 gigabytes. It is not really possible to copy this size, which is why I am looking for a quicker, alternate solution. Regarding the replica, is [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) what I need to look at?

Comment: Yes. make your old server as primary and new as secondary. You can setup  arbiter on any machine. Once your data is transferred, shutdown primary and arbiter machine. However, you do need to restart mongod on new machine without replica flags.

Comment: Just be warned that replica is slowest and will take quite bit of time. However moving physical files will be faster option depending on your network bandwidth.

Comment: OK that's good to know @Saleem . Do you know why the .1 data files aren't preserved by mongorestore?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what is `.1` file is?  Honestly, I never saw such files with mongodump

Comment: @Saleem the .1 is not from the dump, it's one of the DB data files. dump produces the json & bson files. what I'm asking is why mongorestore doesn't restore the .1 files -- is it because they aren't needed? or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: What are your `db.stats()` for the original and restored database, and what versions of MongoDB are you restoring from & to? The first file allocated by the MMAP storage engine will be 64MB per DB so if the actual data size is less than this it's possible that restored data will be more compact and not require as many data files. Depending on the MongoDB versions you are restoring to/from it's also possible the storage allocation will increase. As long as collections/objects/indexes counts and data size match up, differences in storage size and number of data files are likely not a concern.

Comment: @Stennie I don't know how to get the stats for the restored database. Using mongo shell it is always connecting me to the localhost DB which is the original DB.