# what is information located at /var/lib/mongo/dbname.ns

Tags: mongodb

May I know what kind of information is located at this directory. When I tried to know I wrote following two commands

on linux box and got the following result:

```
cd /var/lib/mongo/
ls
collection-29102--3481430970472628260.wt 
index-19537--3481430970472628260.wt       
_mdb_catalog.wt
collection-2910--3481430970472628260.wt  
index-19539--3481430970472628260.wt       
mongod.lock
collection-29104--3481430970472628260.wt 
index-19541--3481430970472628260.wt      
sizeStorer.wt
collection-29106--3481430970472628260.wt 
index-19543--3481430970472628260.wt
storage.bson
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB created files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489611/mongodb-created-files)

Comment: These are not .0 or .1 files even I am not able to see the contents of neither "collection-29104--3481430970472628260.wt" nor "index-19541--3481430970472628260.wt" and WiredTiger , _mdb_catalog.wt and directory "journal" is created in it.